# How to add the class name from object iteration value?

Tags: angular, angular5

I am trying to add the class name from iterator object with some static value.
I am getting error, how to add the class name from iterator?

```
<ul style="font-size: 20px">
    <li *ngFor="let link of socialLinks" [ngClass]="{ 'icon' + link.label}">{{link.label}}</li>
</ul>
```

I am adding `icon` as static and `link.label` from object.

Comment: Use curly bracket if you want to put some condition in ngClass else use it without brackets

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not need of brackets.

```
  <li *ngFor="let link of socialLinks" [ngClass]="'icon' + link.label">{{link.label}}</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

...To add bit more explanation.

When you use attribute binding `[]` on the left side of any attribute then you don't need to use `{{}}` on right side because attribute binding itself evaluate right hand side as an expression.

```
<li *ngFor="let link of socialLinks" [ngClass]="{ 'icon' + link.label}">{{link.label}}</li>
```

So here in this is case you are asking angular to evaluate `"{ 'icon' + link.label}"` whereas `link.label` is already expression. SO that is why you need only at a time like this -

```
<li *ngFor="let link of socialLinks" [ngClass]="'icon' + link.label">{{link.label}}</li>
```